# Javascript: Ocultar botão depois do evento "subscribe"

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Gente neste script do google tem um comenterio escrito "Add code to handle subscribe event." traduzindo "Adicionar código para lidar com evento de assinatura.".

Eu quero saber se tem como eu colocar um codigo nesse lugar para que quando ocorre a ação "subcribe" o botão suma. Se tiver como e você souber o código, pode me passa-lo?

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      // Add code to handle subscribe event.
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

Comment: Se voce puder editar o codigo/div do botao coloca um `id` nele e esconde no if do subscribe. Se o botao estiver sendo gerado automaticamente é um pouco diferente. E qual é essa api que esta usando?

Comment: Google developers

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button?hl=pt-br

Comment: esta usando jquery tambem?

Comment: Não, apenas html e js

Answer (score 1):

Isso já resolve, se estiver usando jquery, nao vai ser diferente, ao inves de remover o botao poderia somente esconder adiv tambem, ai depende do que precisa.

```html
<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      // Add code to handle subscribe event.
      document.getElementById('inscreverse').remove();
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- como a api manipula a div  g-ytsubscribe entao eu coloqeui essa div para ser mais facil de esconder o botao depois -->
<div id="inscreverse">
  <!-- adicionei um texto e um evento de click no botao,somente para simular o que aconteceria, pode tirar quando for o codigo final -->
  <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent" onClick="onYtEvent({eventType:'subscribe'})">inscrever-se </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Esconder a div é até melhor porque eu palenejo colocar um bloqueador que só debloqueio o botão de download pra quem se inscrever, por isso quero que o botão suma caso a pessoa seja inscrita, o que fez me ajudou a entender, mas preciso fazer com o botão inscrever-se do youtube que vou colocar no site.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda man :-D